# Discrepancy between path when running Django app vs. running main module in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web-app with a directory/file structure like so:

```
matrix/
    matrix/
        settings.py
        __init__.py
    view/
        get_matrix.py
        __init__.py
    settings.py
    __init__.py
```

`settings.py` (the one in the top-level directory) is a simple one-liner with a property:

```
SOME_PROPERTY="FOO"
```

and finally this is `get_matrix.py`:

```
import settings

def foo_bar_op():
    print settings.PROPERTY

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_bar_op()
```

**Problem**

When I run the web-app, it runs fine and there is no problem.  However, when I run `python get_matrix.py` by itself, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named settings
```

I looked at the `sys.path` when the web-app runs and it includes the top-level directory as the first entry.  That would explain how it's finding `settings.py`.

Why doesn't the main module find `settings.py`?  Is it confused that there are two directories named `matrix`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because settings.py is not on the PYTHONPATH when running outside of Django. Try this:

```
try:
    import settings
except ImportError,err:
    import sys
    sys.path.append("../")
    import settings


def foo_bar_op():
    print settings.PROPERTY

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_bar_op()
```

This is a common pattern for writing code that is shared by Django and a standalone process.  Especially if you want to use ORM classes written for Django, outside of Django. Then you could also provide a barebones "fake_django_settings.py" for the standalone script.

Comment: And then I do `import settings` after `sys.path.append("../")`, right?  Otherwise, I get `NameError: global name 'settings' is not defined`

Comment: Minor thing: If I write it like you did, I get an "unexpected indent" error. Why does that happen?
I removed the indent for the 2nd `import settings` and it worked.

Comment: This is very dangerous to use 'except Exception'. It's more appropriate here to use 'except ImportError'

Comment: @Sid you're right, copying and pasting it added spaces, while I was using tabs.